# NRoots Results: From Equations to List of Root Values

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

When I use Roots/NRoots, I get a disjunction of conditions as result. The conditions are normally of the type

> x == value

How can I convert this to the list of root values?

Comment: Use `ToRules`  (as noted in `Roots` ref guide page, Properties & Relations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List @@ Roots[x^3 - 5 x + 4 == 0, x][[All, -1]]

(*  {(1/2)*(-1 - Sqrt[17]), 
   (1/2)*(-1 + Sqrt[17]), 1}  *)
```

**EDIT:** To understand a complex expression, decompose it and rebuild it, step-by-step, examining each intermediate step.

```
expr1 = Roots[x^3 - 5 x + 4 == 0, x]

(*  x == (1/2)*(-1 - Sqrt[17]) || 
   x == (1/2)*(-1 + Sqrt[17]) || 
   x == 1  *)
```

The [Head](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) of `expr1` is [Or](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or.html).

```
Head[expr1]

(*  Or  *)
```

Use [Apply (@@)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) to convert to a list

```
expr2 = List @@ expr1

(*  {x == (1/2)*(-1 - Sqrt[17]), 
   x == (1/2)*(-1 + Sqrt[17]), 
   x == 1}  *)
```

Use [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) to extract the values

```
expr3 = expr2[[All, -1]]

(*  {(1/2)*(-1 - Sqrt[17]), 
   (1/2)*(-1 + Sqrt[17]), 1}  *)
```

The original expression above collapses these intermediate steps into a one-liner. Or as suggested in the comments by [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau),

```
x /. {Roots[x^3 - 5 x + 4 == 0, x] // ToRules}

(*  {(1/2)*(-1 - Sqrt[17]), 
   (1/2)*(-1 + Sqrt[17]), 1}  *)
```

Decompose and rebuild step-by-step as required.

Comment: That works. For the uninitiated, what's going on here?